# How to integrate Spark with Scala project in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am using IntelliJ IDE to play with Scala and Spark. In this IDE I created a Scala project with a Scala object (see picture).

[image]

I used the sample Regression code from this [web site](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html).

I also downloaded Spark Framework as a non-Maven user from GitHub (as explained [here](http://sparkjava.com/download.html)).

My question is how to link this Spark Framework with my Scala project? Also do I need to integrate some additional libraries to be able to work with Spark MLLib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend create [simple sbt project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html) with following dependencies in the `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.1" )
```

Then *Open* it via menu which start importing project from sbt.

When IDEA finishes importing\downloading\indexing libraries you can just `ctrl-shift-D` and voilà - you have spark console with syntax perfect highlighting multiline editing and completion.

Then you can create directory `/src/main/scala` if it not exists. Or you could make IDEA create it for you in options:

[image: generate folders]

Next you should create new object in the `scala` directory, select "new scala class - object":

[image: new scala class]

Next write some code in the `main` method in your object, and run it via `ctrl-shift-F10` or context command

[image: run]

And enjoy your results

[image: results]

Comment: How can I open the project to start importing libraries? When I go to File->Open and open the project, then IDEA just opens it without importing anything.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Did you create empty folder with just `build.sbt` file in it and then open it?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like IDEA is downloading Spark libraries now. I will wait to check your last step (ctrl-shift-D)

Comment: So, where do I need to put the Scala object (I apologize for simple questions. Just started learning Scala and Spark few hours ago). Could you please add some screenshot to illustrate this last step.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I've done some screenshots for you, hope you like it

Comment: How can I add a run icon or buttons that makes a `spark-submit --class ... ` every time I want to run something in a cluster?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/saurfang/sbt-spark-submit). Next you can add new run configuration to `spark-submit ...`  task via IDEA.