# Error on integrating Spark with Scala project in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I created a simple SBT project in IntelliJ IDE with the following library dependencies in `build.sbt`:

```
import _root_.sbt.Keys._

name := "untitled"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.1" ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib"  % "1.5.1")
```

The objective is to import Spark and MLLIB of Spark, and then to create a Scala object as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901160/how-to-integrate-spark-with-scala-project-in-intellij-ide).

However, the following error occurs on importing:

> ```
> SBT project import
> [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version: [warn] *
> ```
>
> org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:(2.11.0, 2.11.7) [warn] *
>   org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:(3.3.2, 3.0) [warn] *
>   jline:jline:(0.9.94, 2.12.1) [warn] *
>   org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:(1.0.1, 1.0.4)
>   [warn] * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.1, 1.0.4) [warn] *
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:(1.7.10, 1.7.2) [warn] [FAILED ]
>   net.sourceforge.f2j#arpack_combined_all;0.1!arpack_combined_all.jar(src):
>   (0ms) [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
>   C:\Users\Cezar.ivy2\local\net.sourceforge.f2j\arpack_combined_all\0.1\srcs\arpack_combined_all-sources.jar
>   [warn] ==== public: tried [warn]
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/f2j/arpack_combined_all/0.1/arpack_combined_all-0.1-sources.jar
>   [warn] [FAILED ] javax.xml.bind#jsr173_api;1.0!jsr173_api.jar(doc):
>   (0ms) [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
>   C:\Users\Cezar.ivy2\local\javax.xml.bind\jsr173_api\1.0\docs\jsr173_api-javadoc.jar
>   [warn] ==== public: tried [warn]
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jsr173_api/1.0/jsr173_api-1.0-javadoc.jar
>   [warn] [FAILED ] javax.xml.bind#jsr173_api;1.0!jsr173_api.jar(src):
>   (0ms) [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
>   C:\Users\Cezar.ivy2\local\javax.xml.bind\jsr173_api\1.0\srcs\jsr173_api-sources.jar
>   [warn] ==== public: tried [warn]
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jsr173_api/1.0/jsr173_api-1.0-sources.jar
>   [warn] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn] :: FAILED
>   DOWNLOADS :: [warn] :: ^ see resolution messages for details ^ ::
>   [warn] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn] ::
>   net.sourceforge.f2j#arpack_combined_all;0.1!arpack_combined_all.jar(src)
>   [warn] :: javax.xml.bind#jsr173_api;1.0!jsr173_api.jar(doc) [warn] ::
>   javax.xml.bind#jsr173_api;1.0!jsr173_api.jar(src) [warn]
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Comment: Check your which Scala version your Spark installation is using!

Comment: @eliasah: How to check it? I can see "Running Spark version 1.5.1" and I'm using Scala 2.11

Comment: Did you use a prebuilt version or built it yourself?

Comment: @eliasah: I use prebuilt version.

Comment: Usually the prebuilt versions support Scala 2.10. You'll have to build it yourself. You can find the procedure on the official documentation.

Comment: I used to build Spark under Scala 2.11 but this is real pain. Unless you're using 2.11-specific features I recommend just to switch to 2.10.

Answer (score 1):

Spark will not work with Scala 2.11. It uses Scala 2.10, so you need to use a compatible Scala version (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/).

Alternatively, you can, as @eliasah has also mentioned in a comment, build Spark yourself. Instructions on how to build Spark can be found at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html

Comment: I don't agree with you in that. Spark works with Scala 2.11 if you use the proper build.

Comment: @eliasah This is according to the documentation and surely it applies to the prebuild versions of Spark that are referenced in the question from OP.

Comment: Check my comment on the question. Thus your hypothesis is wrong. You should add "prebuilt version"

Comment: In either case, while I agree that building Spark yourself is _a_ solution it is not the only solution to the problem. Speaking for myself (and I run everything on Amazon EMR with preinstalled Spark), it has been way easier to downgrade my code to Scala 2.10.x, which will also solve the problem. I will leave it to @Klausos to decide which solution he prefers.

Comment: I never pretended that it's the only solution and that's why I have given it as a comment. You can update your answer using also my comment and I'll up-vote it!

Comment: I've successfully built Spark under 2.11. Have to change dependencies across the code into 2.11 but everything works fine.