# spark context cannot reslove in MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile with Intellij

Tags: eclipse, scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I try to run Multilayer perceptron classifier example here:https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-ann.html, it seems works well at spark-shell, but not with IDE like Intellij and Eclipse. The problem comes from
`val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt").toDF()`

IDE prompts *cannot resolve symbol sc(sparkcontext)*, but the libraries path has been correctly configure. If anyone can helps me, thanks!

Comment: Did you import the proper libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no such value as `sc` by default. It's imported on spark-shell startup. In any ordinal scala\java\python code you should create it manually.

I've recently made [very low quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901160/how-to-integrate-spark-with-scala-project-in-intellij-ide/33901323#33901323). You can use part about `sbt` and libraries in it.

Next you can use something like following code as template to start.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object Spark extends App {
  val config = new SparkConf().setAppName("odo").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
  val sc = new SparkContext(config)
  val sqlc = new SQLContext(cs)

  import sqlc.implicits._

 //here you code follows
}
```

Next you can just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> it

Comment: Thank you bro! Your reply really helps me, I am looking at your links. It is nice to learn from you.